# How to detect the misuse of a valid password

Tags: asp.net, authentication, security

I'm starting to size up a project where I feel security needs strike a little closer to home.  What tools and techniques could I look at to attempt to raise an alarm when a valid login is used, but the owner of the login has given it away or had it stolen.  I would prefer ASP.NET, then MVC 3, oriented stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a silver bullet, but perhaps you should consider employing some kind of two-factor authentication.  For example: when a user creates an account with you, you require that she provide you with a phone number where she can receive text messages as part of the registration process.  Then, when she attempts to log in, you text her a temporary authentication code to be used in combination with her username and password.

This ads an extra layer of security to the system, because an attacker would have to both know her username and password *and* have physical access to her cell phone in order to compromise her account.

I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you would get a lot of false positives... but you might try checking what IP address the login is coming from.  Most people will log in from the same IP address most of the time, so when that changes, it's at least a warning sign.  If you want to be very strict about security, you could maintain a whitelist (for each account) and require that they get their IP address added to the whitelist before logging in.

Comment: Nice technique, but in SA a large number of people use intermittent 3G connections on public networks, so I see this as a sign of a high frequency of IP address resets.

Comment: Sometimes you can still get the right effect by using IP ranges instead of specific IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

My bank (Chase) does this by checking a secure cookie during my username/password login. If the cookie is missing or corrupted, they require a second form of authentication, which is either a code sent via text to my phone number on file or via email to my email address on file. Once the second form of authentication is complete, they set the secure cookie and then I can login from that browser with only username and password.

Comment: My bank actually also does that, with a number they send you that they require for login.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own Membership provider and add field locked to model, 
check for user being locked on login and do some actions

Comment: That will protect some, but only while the legal user is logged on, or discovers he's already logged on.  In between is still quite a big risk.

Comment: what you mean by in between? all auth actions will go via you custom membership provider

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to think of the factors of the Authentication process, so that you can be sure that you are sufficiently covering things. You can easily get ridiculous with the layers of assurances, but I happen to find that most banks now have a variation on a simple model. All of this is, of course, over SSL

1. User submits account name. Additionally, you can require a secondary piece of information, last 4 of account number or year part of date of birth.
2. Optional, but a good idea: present the user with a counter sign, that is something that verifies the identity of the server. The user selects this at registration and should be looking for this every time they attempt to log in. This aids in preventing phishing.
3. System checks to see if the current system using IP lookup or cookie is associated with the account. If not, presents challenge question along with password input. Otherwise, presents just the password input.

Complicated, but can actually be done in 2 pages and more secure than is usually required.

I've presented this workflow to a few bank clients and they usually remove one or two of the checks for a balance of user friendliness.

With phones with text capabilities being so common, the idea of SMS verification code as mentioned by others is also a good idea, though I haven't implemented this in a system yet, personally.